# iOS FMDB fetch about three million items: Terminate due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, out-of-memory, fmdb

Recently I am working on an app about sqlite. I used FMDB (2.6.2) and iOS is 10.2.0 . There are about three million items in an database. And every item has three colomns:`id` `name` `logo`.

When showing all the data on UI, the requiremens of the app is blow:

- You can not use the way of fetching more data (just like use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` scroll to bottom to load more,but you still can use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`)
- UI must be very smooth when you scroll
- Don‘t cause memory overflow

According to the requirments, I test some conditions.

I can satisfy the first and sceond requirement. But the last one ,I find when you fetch all the three million items from db once or many times, it still can cause memory overflow.

Here is my code to fetch data in background queue：

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    while (_usersArrM.count < _countNum)
    {
        NSUInteger offset = _usersArrM.count + usersFromDBOffsetCount;
        if (offset > _countNum)
        {
            offset = _countNum - _usersArrM.count;
        }
        else
        {
            offset = usersFromDBOffsetCount;
        }

        NSString  *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from user limit %zd, %zd", _usersArrM.count, offset];

        [_queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

            FMResultSet *userModelRS = [db executeQuery:sql];
            while (userModelRS.next)
            {
                AndyUserModel *userModel = [[AndyUserModel alloc] init];

                userModel.Id = [userModelRS intForColumn:@"id"];
                userModel.name = [userModelRS stringForColumn:@"name"];
                userModel.logo = [userModelRS stringForColumn:@"logo"];
                [_usersArrM addObject:userModel];
            }

            [userModelRS close];
        }];

        [_queue close];
    }
});
```

*Tips:*

- `_usersArrM` : a `NSMutableAarray` the datasource of `UITableView`
- `_countNum`: the nums of items in db
- `usersFromDBOffsetCount`: `static NSUInteger const usersFromDBOffsetCount = 2000;`
- `_queue`: `_queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:dbPath];`
- db download: http://okufme2fh.bkt.clouddn.com/test.db.zip

---

I guess the issue that causes memory overflow is `_queue`, even though `[_queue close]`, some memory about db can`t be released correctly . And the reult is when loop some times, app terminate due to memory issue.

Is there one way to release the memory of db completely when one loop is finished . Or what is the correct way to satisfy these requirements for this app.

Thanks.

Comment: try use an `@autoreleasepool{...}` around everything inside the while loop. But still, loading 3 million entries into memory and storing it inside your object sound like too much, cant you find a way to load only the data you need to display at the time? aka some kind of lazy loading

Comment: Run **Instruments** and look what is causing the memory leak.

Comment: I suggest implement *Indexing* is the best approach in this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, instead of adding the entire object to the array, its better to use its indexing (adding the primary key to array). Fetch the object as soon as you want to the load the cell. This will reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: `@autoreleasepool{...}` doesnot work for this scenario, it still causes memeory overflow

Comment: **Instruments** There is no memory leak

Comment: If I fetch the object as soon as I want to the load the cell, it must lead to  one scenario: I scroll the tableView very very fast, fetching the object from db cannot execute as fast as possible as we want. Yeap, UI is blocked sometimes. Can't satisfy the second requirement.

Comment: As per your first point you can use load more with some trick as user can not identify that you are querying for next bunch of data and append into ur current array, by this way you can achieve like Instagram app is doing and other that this it will definitely overflow memory b'cus its 3 million data so.

Comment: And why you are setting limit in your query ? any specific reason ? also use Indexing in SQLITE to faster selection of data from DB.